# How to access to members of a test result in R

Tags: r, anova, dataset, manova

I am conducting the Levene's test as well as Shapiro-Wilk test on a large set of data. I am wondering how do I access to particular parts of a result and store them in a CSV file to simplify reporting results.

For example, a Levene's test results look like this in R:

```
> leveneTest(Var~Label, data = df)

Df F value Pr(>F)
group   3  0.7595 0.5183
      166
```

How can I get only F-value and p-value stored in separate variables? Same as W and p-value in the following:

```
> shapiro.test(df[,i])

Shapiro-Wilk normality test

data:  dfc[, i]
W = 0.70952, p-value < 2.2e-16
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this below? I don't know what is `i` in your code though:

```
library(car)
df = data.frame(Var=runif(100),Label=rep(c("A","B"),50))
test = leveneTest(Var~Label, data = df)
```

To know to access the data, do:

class(test)
[1] "anova"      "data.frame"

So test is a data.frame and you can either use `$` or access it via rows and column names. Since the column names contains spaces in this case, using the matrix way is a bit better (and you know the column you called):

```
Fvalue = test[1,"F value"]
pvalue = test[1,"Pr(>F)"]

Fvalue
> [1] 0.3516209
> pvalue
[1] 0.554563
```

For shapiro, unfortunately they created a new class, so you can check the vignette:

> Value:
>
> ```
>  A list with class ‘"htest"’ containing the following components:
> ```
>
> statistic: the value of the Shapiro-Wilk statistic.
>
> p.value: an approximate p-value for the test.  This is said in
>   Royston
>             (1995) to be adequate for ‘p.value < 0.1’.

So we treat it as a list:

```
names(test)
[1] "statistic" "p.value"   "method"    "data.name"

test$p.value
[1] 0.0002292068
```

Comment: Perfect -- i is just an iterator to iterate over several vectors I want to test. Can you also tell me how to do this with shapiro.test results? The output for that is a bit different. Also, is there any general way to figure out which approach to take in dealing with these situations?